# Illustrator exporting to PDF vectors have gaps

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I'm creating logo with illustrator, and when I export to PDF, where the meshes joins I get gaps which doesnt look good when you work in photoshop or looking in PDF reader.

[image]

I have one solution to fix it - make one shape go under the other. BUT it's not good thing for a logo, if in future it goes to printing and similar things..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to anti-aliasing to the background color, or whatever color the image is sitting on...

Easiest solution is to add a solid fill object (or group appearance fill) behind everything with an appropriate color to anti-alias to in Illustrator. I'd just add a solid green fill behind the entire shape.

To be clear, I'm really not certain *why* any of those shapes may be a "mesh". The appearance would suggest that meshes aren't required at all and would only serve to create additional complexity to basic crescent shapes.

Comment: I'm sure i saw this asked a few other times so it must be a duplicate right?

Comment: @Lucian Yes, most likely. Not up to searching for it at the moment and it's quicker to just answer :)

Comment: Sorry if it's duplicating, but I didnt find what I wanted. If I prepare logo with shape under it. It can become messy in the printing process?

Comment: Not if you're careful.

Comment: @wyy No. The underlying shape will not cause any detrimental effects anywhere. It'll merely ensure the internal edges always anti-alias to *that* color when needed. The only *possible* issue would be if the existing shapes are using transparency. Then the underlying fill would show through. But soft transparency within a logo is customarily more trouble than any underlying solid fill.

Comment: @wyy also due to the way printing works it will not cause a antialiasing band